# Rails ActiveRecord/Arel query aggregate column with select()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I've got two basic models with a join table. I've added a scope to compute a count through the relation and expose it as an attribute/psuedo-column. Everything works fine, but I'd now like to query a subset of columns and include the count column, but I don't know how to reference it.

**tldr; How can I include an aggregate such as a count in my Arel query while also selecting a subset of columns?**

Models are `Employer` and `Employee`, joined through `Job`. Here's the relevant code from `Employer`:

```
class Employer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :employees, through: :jobs

  scope :include_counts, -> do
    left_outer_joins(:employees).
      group("employers.id").
      select("employers.*, count(employees.*) as employees_count")
  end
end
```

This allows me to load an employer with counts:

```
employers = Employer.include_counts.where(id: 1)
```

And then reference the count:

```
count = employers[0].employees_count
```

I'm loading the record in my controller, which then renders it. I don't want to render more fields than I need to, though. Prior to adding the count, I could do this:

```
employers = Employer.where(id: 1).select(:id, :name)
```

When I add my `include_counts` scope, it basically ignores the `select()`. It doesn't fail, but it ends up including ALL the columns, because of this line in my scope:

```
select("employers.*, count(employees.*) as employees_count")
```

If I remove `employers.*` from the scope, then I don't get ANY columns in my result, with or without a `select()` clause.

I tried this:

```
employers = Employer.include_counts.where(id: 1).select(:id, :name, :employee_counts)
```

...but that produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT employers.*, count(employees.*) as employees_count, id, name, employees_count FROM
```

...and an SQL error because column `employees_count` doesn't exist and `id` and `name` are ambiguous.

The only thing that sort of works is this:

```
employers = Employer.include_counts.where(id: 1).select("employers.id, employers.name, count(employees.*) as employees_count")
```

...but that actually selects ALL the columns in `employers`, due to the scope clause again.

I also don't want that raw SQL leaking into my controller if I can avoid it. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this with Rails/Arel?

If I can't find another way to do the query, I'll probably create another scope or custom finder in the model, so that the controller code is cleaner. I'm open to suggestions for doing that as well, but I'd like to know if there's a simple way to reference computed aggregate columns like this as though they were any other column.