# Is it possible to SELECT from a table and other SELECT query forming additional column in Rails to return Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Prod` and `Tag` models.
I can do in raw SQL:

```
SELECT tags.name, tags.id, a.cnt AS counter
FROM tags, 
    (SELECT tags.name, count(tags.name) AS cnt 
    FROM tags 
    GROUP BY tags.name) AS a 
WHERE a.name = tags.name;
```

and have some handy product quantity indicator above a tag.

But now I wonder whether it is possible to have the same resulting structure but of type `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not mere `ActiveRecord::Result`?

Comment: I have couple of options right now: ```.joins("INNER JOIN (SELECT ...) AS a")``` seems to be doing the right thing but I'm unsure about chaining with it - need to experiment.

Comment: The other option I am to try is creating the association to the same table (tags with same name), but it's still unclear how to implement it.

Comment: I guess I'll do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321861/rails-activerecord-arel-query-aggregate-column-with-select?rq=1). The idea behind this is in my first comment but I ommited ```.select()``` clause after that.

Comment: what exactly do you want ? please describe